# How to get r_fullprofile permission to access education and profession details in linkedin?

Tags: linkedin-api

Linkedin cannot access education, employment/professional details with r_basicprofile. Document says it requires r_fullprofile permission but in app console there is no such permission. How to get r_fullprofile permission to access the education and employment service using linkedin app?

Answer (score 2):

For full profile permission, you must apply to become a LinkedIn Partner.

Partner Program Application Form link:

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

But, it is not easy to get full profile permission. Many applications did not get full profile access permission.

Comment: Yes, I agree it requires the permission from them and its not easy. I have applied for the partner program but havent got any a reply yet.

Comment: Wow, they need to put this in the documentation of the profile api! Maddening!